# Triage review bug lets me know that the question was modified for the "test"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, review-audits

The triage review "test" which asks you to review certain questions that have already been declared either as good or bad questions to check if you're paying attention has a little bug in it.

The bug is that in the comments section the "Date" is written in the original date for that post. Since the other dates are made to look like the question was just asked recently. So it already gave me the inkling that this question is just another test. Though to be honest that question was terrible anyway so it's already a given that I would mark it as unsalvageable.

I'm sorry for the image quality, you'll have to click it to view it in a better resolution.

[image: bug image]

Comment: As you've already pointed out, audits exist to see if you are paying attention.  If you noticed that the dates don't quite line up, you were clearly paying attention and the audit worked.

Comment: I've assumed all possible loopholes are gone to make sure we're not aware that it's another test. :D Thank you for the reply.

Comment: *I've assumed all possible loopholes are gone* Nope. The loopholes are deliberate. Audits are supposed to be obvious because all they're meant to do is make sure the reviewer is paying attention (as opposed to just clicking "Looks OK" over and over to get the review badge).